# How to return data from server to page and set it to localStorage in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, svelte, sveltekit, sapper

`Context` is an object which I want to save to LocalStorage. In `page.server.js` I am returning context like this:

```
      return { success: true, userInfo: context};
```

In `page.svelte` I can access the object and it's attributes. There is a function which saves the object to localStorage which works when there are no redirects and I call it like this:

```
            {#if form?.success}
              {$LoginStatus = {
                loggedIn: true,
                userInfo: form?.userInfo
              }}
```

My problem is that the page redirects if the user is logged in and (quoting svelte's documentation) the page is ephemeral. What I think the problem is that the page redirects to another page before it can call the function to save `context` to localStorage.

How can I fix this problem so that `context` gets stored to localStorage successfully?

Comment: I don't know svelte, but: I think you could move your logic to a place that is ran every time your app is opened (for react it would be `index.jsx` instead of inside of `App.jsx` main component). The second solution could be just duplicating your code into the second page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the SvelteKit [form actions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions) API.

You are trying to persist data returned from the form action in the page component on the client/browser. However, the main purpose for values returned from a form action is just to update the form (for example: display validation errors or a success message.)

Ideally the form action should persist the data itself before returning. Now, the form action does not have access to localStorage, so you should use something like a database and/or cookie.

If the form action updates a database, the SvelteKit page can load the updated data in its [`load()`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) function.

Now, when logging in a user just updating the database is not enough: credentials need to be saved on the client (browser). So the database server usually returns credentials that can be saved in the browser. The form action will receive these credentials (on the server side of SvelteKit) and send them to the client/browser side of SvelteKit via [cookies](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#sveltejs-kit-cookies).

These cookies will be sent in the headers of all future requests. By default, these cookies cannot be read by JavaScript, but that page [`load()`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) function runs on server. So the `load()` function can read the cookie and return the values, which can be accessed from the SvelteKit page from its `data` prop.

Just using the cookie should be enough, but for completeness: after you get the `data` prop, you are free to save it to localeStorage at that point.

---

A log in form can be quite daunting, since it requires combining multiple things like SvelteKit's cookies, form API, etc. Just learning the SvelteKit page routing + `load()` is difficult enough!

It is possible to add log in to a SvelteKit project without all these things by using a 3rd-party authentication service. I recommend [Userfront](https://userfront.com/). They don't have official guides for SvelteKit, but I made a sample project (using an old version of SvelteKit): https://github.com/Leftium/userfrontKit/

Userfront has [guides for plain HTML, React, and Vue](https://userfront.com/quickstart) which would help you create your own SvelteKit version.

I *have* integrated Userfront with the most recent version of SvelteKit using form actions (unfortunately cannot share.)

The nice thing about Userfront and SvelteKit is you can choose the level of integration:

- Use Userfront's [toolkit](https://userfront.com/quickstart) with pre-made forms.
- Use Userfront's [core JS API](https://userfront.com/docs/js) to roll your own SvelteKit forms (client-side only, requires JS)
- Use Userfront's [client-to-server API](https://userfront.com/docs/api-client) to roll your own SvelteKit progressive forms (server or client+server, no JS required)

All the methods above store user info/credentials in a cookie which can be accessed from both the server and client.

Comment: I took a different approach. I was actually routing from the server side using Redirect from sveltekit. Since the redirect was server side, my browser got redirected before it received any data and hence it could not store anything to localStorage. Approach #2 was to redirect from the browser but sveltekit threw errors if I tried to access window object from javascript. Approach #3 worked for me (but it had side effects). I let the browser do it's thing by storing the data received to localStorage and then add a home button which would only be shown depending on the state of the data.